# Django Rendering HTML files ISSUE

Tags: django, django-urls

This might be something simple, but this is an error I've never faced before. Instead of rendering the template normally, Im getting plain HTML Code...

Just like a Plain Text File, without a single error, it just suddenly started showing plain HTML text. Not getting a single error message...

View File

```
def editar_cliente(request, cliente_id):
    cliente = Cliente.objects.get(pk=cliente_id)
    datos = {'cliente': cliente}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('tipo') and request.POST.get('nombre') and request.POST.get('apellidos') and request.POST.get('cedula') and request.POST.get('email') and request.POST.get('telefono'):
            cliente.tipo = request.POST.get('tipo')
            cliente.nombre = request.POST.get('nombre')
            cliente.apellidos = request.POST.get('apellidos')
            cliente.cedula = request.POST.get('cedula')
            cliente.email = request.POST.get('email')
            cliente.telefono = request.POST.get('telefono')
            cliente.plan = request.POST.get('plan')
            cliente.mbps_w = request.POST.get('mbps_w')
            cliente.mbps_f = request.POST.get('mbps_f')
            cliente.subida = request.POST.get('subida')
            cliente.bajada = request.POST.get('bajada')
            cliente.zona = request.POST.get('zona')
            cliente.direccion = request.POST.get('direccion')

            cliente.save()
            return render(request, 'clientes/listado.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'clientes/editar_cliente.html', datos, {'error': 'Faltan datos'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'clientes/editar_cliente.html', datos)
```

Html Template

```
{% extends "../index_master.html" %}
{% load static %}
<title>Valnet | {{cliente.nombre}} {{cliente.apellidos}}</title>
<link href="{% static 'info.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'forms.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

<script>
  function switchField()
  {
    if (document.getElementById('w').checked) {
      document.getElementById('wireless').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('fibra').style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('f').checked) {
      document.getElementById('wireless').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('fibra').style.display = 'block';
    }
  }

</script>
<style>
  #fibra, #wireless {
  display: none;
}

#f input:checked ~ .grid-container #fibra {
  display: block;
}
#w input:checked ~ .grid-container #wireless {
  display: block;
}
</style>
{% block content %}
<div class="right_col" role="main">

  {% if cliente.tipo == 'Residencial' %}
  <div class="articulo_form">
    <h1 style="text-align:left;" class="formheader"><b>Cliente Residencial</b></h1>
    <h4 style="text-align:right; font-size:small; text-decoration:underline; margin-top:-30px;">Cliente ID:{{cliente.id}}</h4>
    <hr>
    <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="radio" id="tipo" name="tipo" value="Residencial" checked hidden>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="nombre" class="col-4 col-form-label">{{ cliente.nombre }}</label> 
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fa fa-address-card"></i>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <input id="nombre" name="nombre" value="{{ cliente.nombre }}" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="apellidos" class="col-4 col-form-label">Apellidos</label> 
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <input id="apellidos" value="{{ cliente.apellidos }}" name="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos del Cliente" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="email" class="col-4 col-form-label">Email</label> 
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <input id="email" value="{{ cliente.email }}" name="email" placeholder="Correo Electronico" type="email" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="phone" class="col-4 col-form-label">Telefono</label> 
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <input id="phone" value="{{ cliente.telefono }}" name="telefono" placeholder="No. de Contacto" type="number" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="cedula" class="col-4 col-form-label">C&eacute;dula</label> 
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <input id="cedula" value="{{ cliente.cedula }}" name="cedula" placeholder="Ced. de identidad" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="zona" class="col-4 col-form-label">Zona</label> 
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class='bx bxs-map' ></i>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <input id="zona" value="{{ cliente.zona }}" name="zona" placeholder="Area de ubicacion" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="zona" class="col-4 col-form-label">Direcci&oacute;n</label> 
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class='bx bx-map'></i>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <textarea name="direccion" id="direccion" placeholder="Escriba la direcci&oacute;n del Cliente...">{{cliente.direccion}}</textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="plan" class="col-4 col-form-label">Plan</label> 
          <div class="col-8">
              <input onload="switchField()" onclick="switchField()" type="radio" name="plan" id="w" value="wireless">
              <label for="wireless">Wireless</label>
              <input onload="switchField()" onclick="switchField()" type="radio" name="plan" id="f" value="fibra">
              <label for="fibra">Fibra &Oacute;ptica</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="categoria" class="col-4 col-form-label">Seleccion el Plan</label> 
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class='bx bx-signal-4'></i>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="grid-container">
            <select name="mbps_f" id="fibra">
              <option value="10/5 Mbps">10/5 Mbps</option>
              <option value="20/10 Mbps">20/10 Mbps</option>
              <option value="40/30 Mbps">40/30 Mbps</option>
              <option value="60/50 Mbps">60/50 Mbps</option>
              <option value="100/75 Mbps">100/75 Mbps</option>
              <option value="200/150 Mbps">200/150 Mbps</option>
              <option value="250/200 Mbps">250/200 Mbps</option>
              <option value="350/300 Mbps">350/300 Mbps</option>
            </select>
        <!--Select Wireless-->
            <select name="mbps_w" id="wireless">
              <option value="5/3 Mbps">5/3 Mbps</option>
              <option value="10/5 Mbps">10/5 Mbps</option>
              <option value="15/7 Mbps">15/7 Mbps</option>
              <option value="20/10 Mbps">20/10 Mbps</option>
              <option value="30/15 Mbps">30/15 Mbps</option>
            </select>Actualmente, Plan:{{cliente.plan}}{% if cliente.plan == 'fibra'%}{{cliente.mbps_f}}{% endif %}{% if cliente.plan == 'wireless'%}{{cliente.mbps_w}}{% endif %}
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="f_nac" class="col-4 col-form-label">Fecha de Nacimiento</label> 
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <input id="f_nac" name="f_nac" value="{{cliente.f_nac}}" placeholder="Fecha de nacimiento" type="date" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="offset-4 col-8">
          <button style="background-color:#001b36; border:none;" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i style="color:#f5811f;" class='bx bx-refresh' ></i>Actualizar Cliente</button>
          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary">Resetear Valores</button>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  {% endif %}
  
  {% if cliente.tipo == 'Empresarial' %}
  <div class="articulo_form">
    <h1 class="formheader">Formulario <b>Cliente Empresarial</b></h1>
    <hr>
    <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="radio" id="tipo" name="tipo" value="Empresarial" checked hidden>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="nombre" class="col-4 col-form-label">Nombre de Empresa</label> 
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fa fa-address-card"></i>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <input id="nombre" name="nombre" value="{{cliente.nombre}}" placeholder="Nombre de Cliente" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="apellidos" class="col-4 col-form-label">Razon Social</label> 
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <input id="apellidos" value="{{cliente.apellidos}}" name="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos del Cliente" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="email" class="col-4 col-form-label">Email</label> 
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <input id="email" name="email" value="{{cliente.email}}" placeholder="Correo Electronico" type="email" class="form-control" >
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="phone" class="col-4 col-form-label">Telefono</label> 
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <input id="phone" name="telefono" value="{{ cliente.telefono }}" placeholder="No. de Contacto" type="number" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="rnc" class="col-4 col-form-label">RNC</label> 
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <input id="rnc" name="rnc" value="{{ cliente.rnc }}" placeholder="RNC de Empresa" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="zona" class="col-4 col-form-label">Zona</label> 
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class='bx bxs-map' ></i>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <input id="zona" name="zona" value="{{ cliente.zona }}" placeholder="Area de ubicacion" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="zona" class="col-4 col-form-label">Direcci&oacute;n</label> 
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class='bx bx-map'></i>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <textarea name="direccion" id="direccion" placeholder="Escriba la direcci&oacute;n del Cliente...">{{ cliente.direccion }}</textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="plan" class="col-4 col-form-label">Plan</label> 
          <div class="col-8">
            <input onclick="javascript:showField();" type="radio" name="plan" id="w" value="wireless">
            <label for="wireless">Wireless</label>
            <input onclick="javascript:showField();" type="radio" name="plan" id="f" value="fibra">
            <label for="fibra">Fibra &Oacute;ptica</label>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="zona" class="col-4 col-form-label">Plan Asignado</label> 
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class='bx bx-up-arrow-alt' ></i>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <input id="mbps" name="subida" placeholder="00" type="number">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class='bx bx-down-arrow-alt' ></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <input id="mbps" name="bajada" placeholder="00" type="number"><span class="suffix">Mbps</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="offset-4 col-8">
          <button style="background-color:#001b36; border:none;" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i style="color:#f5811f;" class='bx bx-refresh' ></i>Actualizar Cliente</button>
          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary">Resetear Valores</button>
        </div>
        </div>
      </form>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% if cliente.tipo == 'Institucional' %}
  <div class="articulo_form">
    <h1 class="formheader">Editar cliente <b>Institucional</b></h1>
    <hr>
    <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="radio" id="tipo" name="tipo" value="Institucional" checked hidden>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="nombre" class="col-4 col-form-label">Nombre de Instituci&oacute;n</label> 
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fa fa-address-card"></i>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <input id="nombre" value="{{cliente.nombre}}" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre de Cliente" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="apellidos" class="col-4 col-form-label">Raz&oacute;n Social</label> 
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <input id="apellidos" value="{{cliente.apellidos}}" name="apellidos" placeholder="Raz&oacute;n Social de la Instituci&oacute;n" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="email" class="col-4 col-form-label">Email</label> 
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <input id="email" value="{{cliente.email}}" name="email" placeholder="Correo Electronico" type="email" class="form-control" >
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="phone" class="col-4 col-form-label">Telefono</label> 
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <input id="phone" value="{{cliente.telefono}}" name="telefono" placeholder="No. de Contacto" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="cedula" class="col-4 col-form-label">RNC</label> 
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <input id="rnc" value="{{cliente.rnc}}" name="rnc" placeholder="RNC de Organizaci&oacute;n" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="zona" class="col-4 col-form-label">Zona</label> 
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class='bx bxs-map' ></i>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <input id="zona" value="{{cliente.zona}}" name="zona" placeholder="Area de ubicacion" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="zona" class="col-4 col-form-label">Direcci&oacute;n</label> 
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class='bx bx-map'></i>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <textarea name="direccion" id="direccion" placeholder="Escriba la direcci&oacute;n del Cliente...">{{cliente.direccion}}</textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="plan" class="col-4 col-form-label">Plan</label> 
          <div class="col-8">
            {% if cliente.plan == 'wireless' %}<span>El cliente tiene Plan Wireless</span>{% endif %}
            {% if cliente.plan == 'fibra' %}<span>El cliente tiene Plan Fibra Optica</span>{% endif %}
            
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="zona" class="col-4 col-form-label">Plan Asignado</label> 
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class='bx bx-up-arrow-alt' ></i>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <input id="mbps" name="subida" placeholder="00" type="number">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class='bx bx-down-arrow-alt' ></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <input id="mbps" name="bajada" placeholder="00" type="number"><span class="suffix">Mbps</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="offset-4 col-8">
          <button style="background-color:#001b36; border:none;" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i style="color:#f5811f;" class='bx bx-refresh' ></i>Actualizar Cliente</button>
          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary">Resetear Valores</button>
       </form> 
        {% endif %} <script>
    function redirectToURL() {
      window.location = "{% url 'listado' %}";
    }
  </script>
        <button style="text-align: right;" onclick="redirectToURL()" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm"><i class='bx bx-arrow-back'></i> Volver al Listado</button>
      </div>

        </div>
      
   
</div>  
 

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Could you add your code and images of whats happening?

Comment: Hello! here is a img of whats happening https://ibb.co/6nfzhBg

Comment: Kindly share your view file and html template file too.

Comment: Hello Vinita, Thank you, I just edited the question and added View and Html Template, hope you guys can help me. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

There's no `<body>` or `<head>` opening and closing tags in the correct positions in your HTML.  Fix this and it will probably solve your issue.

Html structure should take this shape...

Some file like `templates/base.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>{{some_title}}</title>
  <style type='text/css'>
  /* Some CSS */ 
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  {% block content %} {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Now in a file like `templates/clientes/editar_cliente.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

I am the content of the page

{% endblock %}
```

Render with code like:

```
def editar_cliente(request, cliente_id):
    return render(
        request,
        'clientes/editar_cliente.html'
        {'some_title':'Editar Cliente'}
```

Renders to:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Editar Cliente</title>
  <style type='text/css'>
  /* Some CSS */ 
  </style>
</head>

<body>

I am the content of the page

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello Thank you for your answer, I added <body> and <head> tags and still not rendering properly, i found that im placing the the body and html tags in the index_master, however this started happening suddenly, I wasn't even touching the HTML when this happened.